# displayname attribute vs display attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, displayattribute, .net-attributes

What is difference between `DisplayName` attribute and `Display` attribute in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

They both give you the same results but the key difference I see is that you cannot specify a `ResourceType` in `DisplayName` attribute. For an example in MVC 2, you had to subclass the `DisplayName` attribute to provide resource via localization. `Display` attribute (new in MVC3 and .NET4) supports `ResourceType` overload as an "out of the box" property.

Comment: Good to know! Was about to implement a custom attribute to load the display value from the .resx file, then happened on this question. Display attribute is the way to go when developing localized applications.

Answer (score 166):

`DisplayName` sets the `DisplayName` in the model metadata. For example:

```
[DisplayName("foo")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

and if you use in your view the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```

it would generate:

```
<label for="MyProperty">foo</label>
```

`Display` does the same, but also allows you to set other metadata properties such as Name, Description, ...

Brad Wilson has a [nice blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) covering those attributes.

Comment: +1 - probably a much more helpful than mine (now deleted); too early in the morning for me :)

Comment: I had problems with PropertyDescriptor and using Display(name.. when calling @descriptor.DisplayName, it will only work using DisplayName, not Display(name..).

Answer (score 43):

I think the current answers are neglecting to highlight the actual important and significant differences and what that means for the intended usage. While they might both work in certain situations because the implementer built in support for both, they have different usage scenarios. Both can annotate properties and methods but here are some important differences:

**DisplayAttribute**

- defined in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly
- can be used on parameters and fields
- lets you set additional properties like `Description` or `ShortName`
- **can be localized with resources**

**DisplayNameAttribute**

- DisplayName is in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace in `System.dll`
- can be used on classes and events
- **cannot be localized with resources**

The assembly and namespace speaks to the intended usage and localization support is the big kicker. `DisplayNameAttribute` has been around since .NET 2 and seems to have been intended more for naming of developer components and properties in the legacy property grid, not so much for things visible to end users that may need localization and such.

`DisplayAttribute` was introduced later in .NET 4 and seems to be designed specifically for labeling members of data classes that will be end-user visible, so it is more suitable for DTOs, entities, and other things of that sort. I find it rather unfortunate that they limited it so it can't be used on classes though.

EDIT: Looks like latest .NET Core source allows `DisplayAttribute` to be used on classes now as well.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps this is specific to .net core, I found DisplayName would not work but Display(Name=...) does.  This may save someone else the troubleshooting involved :)

```
//using statements
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  //needed for Display annotation
using System.ComponentModel;  //needed for DisplayName annotation

public class Whatever
{
    //Property
    [Display(Name ="Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}


//cshtml file
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
```