# Difference between Display(Name) and DisplayName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [displayname attribute vs display attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243665/displayname-attribute-vs-display-attribute)

Is there any difference between `Display(Name="MyName")` and  `DisplayName("MyName")` or is it only a feature of ASP.NET MVC ? 
I'm talking about the namespace **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**.

Comment: Possible douplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243665/displayname-attribute-vs-display-attribute