# Difference between these 2 Display attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

What is the difference between these 2 Display attributes?

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Status")]
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public string StatusName;
```

These are inside a buddy metadata class using mvc5 and EF 6 in VS2012.

The first one will throw this message.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[displayname attribute vs display attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243665/displayname-attribute-vs-display-attribute)

DisplayName sets the DisplayName in the model metadata. For example:

```
[DisplayName("foo")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

and if you use in your view the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```

it would generate:

```
<label for="MyProperty">foo</label>
```

Display does the same, but also allows you to set other metadata properties such as Name, Description