# Html.GetEnumSelectList - Getting Enum values with spaces

Tags: c#, html, razor, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

I was using `asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Salary))"` in my Razor view with a select tag, to populate the list values based on the `enum Salary`.

However, my enum contains some items which I would like to have spaces within. E.g. one of the items is `PaidMonthly`, but when I display this using `Html.GetEnumSelectList`, I would like it to be displayed as `"Paid Monthly"` (with a space in it)

I tried using the `Description` attribute over each member in the enum, however when the select box renders it uses the raw value only.

Can anyone please help me out with this matter?

(My Code sample) -> Using ASP.NET Core 1.0

Razor View:

```
<select asp-for="PersonSalary" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Enums.Salary))">
</select>
```

Enum Salary:

```
public enum Salary
{
    [Description("Paid Monthly")]
    PaidMonthly = 1,
    PaidYearly = 2
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried

Comment: Try with `[Display(Name = "Paid Monthly")]`

Comment: Actually, I did try that too. Doesn't work though :\

Comment: Try what Stephen said then use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Salary)`, assuming your list is a dropdown list...

Comment: Hi Jay, unfortunately I cannot seem to find the definition of "Html.EnumDropDownListFor" in my razor view. PS: I am using ASP.NET Core 1.0

Comment: You need to tag your questions correctly :)

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I just had to use the other method of `GetEnumSelectList<>`, and in the Razor view we need to use the Display attribute.

Here is the code:

Razor View:

```
<select asp-for="PersonSalary" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Enums.Salary>()"></select>
```

Enum Salary:

```
public enum Salary
{
    [Display(Name="Paid Monthly")]
    PaidMonthly = 1,
    PaidYearly = 2
}
```

Comment: This is highly confusing since you're supposed to use `[DisplayName(...)]` for standard model properties. `:/`

Comment: @qJake `System.ComponentModel.DisplayAttribute` (for `[Display]`) replaces the older `DisplayNameAttribute` (for `[DisplayName]`) in .NET 4.0. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243665/displayname-attribute-vs-display-attribute

Comment: I think the important part was switching from `[Description("Paid Monthly")]` to `[Display(Name="Paid Monthly")]`, not switching from a non-generic method to a generic version.