# Split enum camel case when using Html.GetEnumSelectList<Enum>()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Assuming we have some string extension method that splits camel casing (as one might use for presentation of an enum), is there any way that this can be applied to the `asp-items` attribute on a select list as per

```
<select asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Enum>()">
    ...    </select>
```

Or do we just have to generate a `new SelectList()` in the ViewModel to achieve this?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052794/html-getenumselectlist-getting-enum-values-with-spaces) any use?

Comment: Ah, actually it is (not sure why it wasn't suggested when I posted). I suppose the question still stands as to whether there is any scope for manipulation with this method, especially if one doesn't really want data annotations on their enums.