# Using [JsonProperty("name")] in ModelState.Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

We have a couple of models that override the name via JsonProperty, but this causes an issue when we get validation errors through ModelState. For example:

```
class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [Required]
    public string MyModelId {get;set;}
}

class MyModelController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        /* etc... */
    }
}
```

The above Post will return the error `The MyModelId field is required.` which isn't accurate. We'd like this to say `The id field is required.`. We've attempted using `[DataMember(Name="id")]` but get the same result.

**Question 1:** Is there a way we can get ModelState errors to show the JSON property name rather than the C# property name aside from providing our own error messages on every [Required] attribute?

## -- Update --

I've been playing around with this and found a "do-it-yourself" method for re-creating the error messages using custom property names. I'm really hoping there's a built-in way to do this, but this seems to do the job...

https://gist.github.com/Blackbaud-JasonTremper/b64dc6ddb460afa1698daa6d075857e4

**Question 2**: Can ModelState.Key be assumed to match the `<parameterName>.<reflectedProperty>` syntax or are there cases where this might not be true?

**Question 3**: Is there an easier way to determine what the JSON parameter name is expected to be rather than searching via reflection on `[DataMember]` or `[JsonProperty]` attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using `DisplayName` attribute?

[displayname attribute vs display attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243665/displayname-attribute-vs-display-attribute)

Also, you can assign an error message to `[Required]` attribute.

`[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]`

Comment: I did try [DisplayName] and it didn't work. However according to you're link the [Display] property did the job (maybe that's what you meant?). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem, I modified some code from your link to fit my WebAPI.  `modelState` will also store the old key which is the variable name of the model, plus the Json Property names.

1. First, create the filter `ValidateModelStateFilter`
2. Add `[ValidateModelStateFilter]` above controller method

The filter source code:

```
public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var descriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            var parameters = descriptor.GetParameters();

            var subParameterIssues = modelState.Keys
                                               .Where(s => s.Contains("."))
                                               .Where(s => modelState[s].Errors.Any())
                                               .GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('.')))
                                               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var argument = actionContext.ActionArguments[parameter.ParameterName];

                if (subParameterIssues.ContainsKey(parameter.ParameterName))
                {
                    var subProperties = subParameterIssues[parameter.ParameterName];
                    foreach (var subProperty in subProperties)
                    {
                        var propName = subProperty.Substring(subProperty.IndexOf('.') + 1);
                        var property = parameter.ParameterType.GetProperty(propName);
                        var validationAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);

                        var value = property.GetValue(argument);

                        modelState[subProperty].Errors.Clear();
                        foreach (var validationAttribute in validationAttributes)
                        {
                            var attr = (ValidationAttribute)validationAttribute;
                            if (!attr.IsValid(value))
                            {
                                var parameterName = GetParameterName(property);
                                // modelState.AddModelError(subProperty, attr.FormatErrorMessage(parameterName));
                                modelState.AddModelError(parameterName, attr.FormatErrorMessage(parameterName));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }

    private string GetParameterName(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var dataMemberAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<DataMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (dataMemberAttribute?.Name != null)
        {
            return dataMemberAttribute.Name;
        }

        var jsonProperty = property.GetCustomAttributes<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (jsonProperty?.PropertyName != null)
        {
            return jsonProperty.PropertyName;
        }

        return property.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a version of this for AspNetCore? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameter type, get the json name, and then replace the property name with the json name. Something like this:

```
var invalidParameters = (from m in actionContext.ModelState
                         where m.Value.Errors.Count > 0
                         select new InvalidParameter
                         {
                              ParameterName = m.Key,
                              ConstraintViolations = (from msg in m.Value.Errors select msg.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                         }).AsEnumerable().ToArray();

if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Count == 1)
{
    var nameMapper = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var property in actionContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters[0].ParameterType.GetProperties())
    {
        object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyNameAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length != 1) continue;

        nameMapper.Add(property.Name, ((JsonPropertyNameAttribute) attributes[0]).Name);
    }

    var modifiedInvalidParameters = new List<InvalidParameter>();


    foreach (var invalidParameter in invalidParameters)
    {
        if(invalidParameter.ParameterName != null && nameMapper.TryGetValue(invalidParameter.ParameterName, out var mappedName))
        {
            var modifiedConstraintViolations = new List<string>();

            foreach (var constraintViolation in invalidParameter.ConstraintViolations ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
            {
                modifiedConstraintViolations.Add(constraintViolation.Replace(invalidParameter.ParameterName, mappedName));
            }

            modifiedInvalidParameters.Add(new InvalidParameter
            {
                ParameterName = mappedName,
                ConstraintViolations = modifiedConstraintViolations.ToArray()
            });
        }
        else
        {
            modifiedInvalidParameters.Add(invalidParameter);
        }
    }

    invalidParameters = modifiedInvalidParameters.ToArray();
}
```

```
public struct InvalidParameter
{
    [JsonPropertyName("parameter_name")]
    public string? ParameterName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("constraint_violations")]
    public string[]? ConstraintViolations { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone stumbling across the same issue in .NET 6/7**

This was recently fixed in .NET 7:

In order to use `JsonPropertyName` in `System.Text.Json.Serialization`, add the following to your configuration in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => 
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SystemTextJsonValidationMetadataProvider()));
```

In order to use `JsonProperty.Name` in `Newtonsoft.Json`, add the following to your configuration in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => 
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonValidationMetadataProvider()));
```

[.NET 7 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-json-property-names-in-validation-errors)

[.NET 7 Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39010)