# How to create a strongly type label for the enum dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

How to create a strongly type label for the enum dropdown. So I have one enum dropdown and I want to have a label for it but I want it to be strongly typed to the enum property. Is it not possible?

Model:

```
  public class CourseEnumsModel
    {
        public CourseEnums OptionSelected { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }
    }
```

ENUMS:

```
   public enum CourseEnums
    {
        Java = 0,
        CSharp = 1,
        RubyOnRails = 2
    }
```

Views:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.CourseEnumsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<form method="post">
 // ONE STRONGLY TYPED LABEL HERE FOR THE DROPDOWN
   @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.OptionSelected)
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

We have **Display Label** for the basic string properties

```
<dt>
    // I want something like this for the enum dropdown
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should work

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OptionSelected )

public class CourseEnumsModel
    {
        DisplayName("<YOUR NAME>")
        public CourseEnums OptionSelected { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you show me the output you are getting im sry im nt on my dev machine

Comment: Is there any difference between `//[DisplayName("<YOUR NAME>")]
        [Display(Name ="<YOUR NAME>")]`. Both seem to work

Comment: [displayname attribute vs display attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243665/displayname-attribute-vs-display-attribute)