# Proper syntax for altering the VB property name when displayed using razor

Tags: html, vb.net, razor

My property name is "UglyPropertyName" and I want to change the Display Name to "New Role" in my view when using

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.UglyPropertyName)
```

With C#, putting [Display(Name="Some New Name")] above the class property will change the display name. What is the syntax to do this in VB.net?

```
Public Class SomeVBClass
    Private _UglyPropertyName As String

    Public Property UglyPropertyame As String
        Get
            Return _UglyPropertyName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _UglyPropertyName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

//Snippet From .vbhtml view

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.UglyPropertyName)
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.UglyPropertyName)
</dd>
```

Currently the @Html.DisplayNameFor will use the property name "UglyPropertyName". I want it to be something like "Formatted Property Name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just slightly different syntax

```
Public Class SomeVBClass
    Private _UglyPropertyName As String

    <DisplayName("Some New Name")>
    Public Property UglyPropertyame As String
        Get
            Return _UglyPropertyName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _UglyPropertyName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: That was my first guess, but that won't even compile.  I have also tried ```<WebDisplayName("Some New Name")>``` Which will compile, but doesn't alter the displayed name.

Comment: If it works on your C# then check for a missing namespace

Comment: Try the attribute `DisplayName`

Comment: Thank you. The final solution was to import ```System.ComponentModel``` and use the syntax ```<DisplayName("Some New Name")>```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41030149/832052) which shows where each attribute Display and DisplayName are located. DisplayName is located in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. They should both do the same thing.

Comment: @Nate usually when this happens (at least in VS 2017) if you hover over the red squigglies, there will be a widget that suggests ways to fix the problem, and it will usually be able to either qualify the reference with the right namespace, or add the right `Imports` directive for you (or even tell you which reference you need to add to your project).